# Android wearable not showing icon set by setcontenticon()

Tags: android, notifications, wear-os

I am using notifications in my app. Each notification has its own specific icon-image. On my phone the notifications work just fine.

However, when I receive the notification on my wearable it always shows the ic_launcher, and not the specific icon-image for the notification.

For testing purposes I am trying to have the wearable show icon_wearable.png in the notification. I already tried putting the icon_wearable.png in different drawable folders (xhdpi hdpi etc.). Right now it is located in the drawable-hdpi folder.

Code used for setting notifications:

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
builder.setContentTitle(someString);
builder.setContentText(message);
builder.setWhen(time.getTimeInMillis());
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.some_image);
builder.setAutoCancel(true);
builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
    builder.extend(new Notification.WearableExtender()
                      .setContentIcon(R.drawable.icon_wearable));
}
```

Can someone please tell me why the wearable is always showing the ic_launcher and not icon_wearable?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you use [v4 support library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#v4) because it allows you to create notifications using the latest notification features such as action buttons and large icons.

Make sure you add this line to your build.gradle file.

```
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.+"
```

And this necessary classes from the support library:

```
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.WearableExtender;
```

For the guideline and sample code on how to use Notification on Wearables, check this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html).

For more information, you are correct to place the icon on the drawable-hdpi directory. Because it is stated in the linked documentation that:

> Place other non-bitmap resources for wearable notifications, such as
>   those used with the `setContentIcon()` method, in the `res/drawable-hdpi directory`.